# The message body cannot be read multiple times. To reuse it store the value after reading

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I have created the code to get the Queue Client data using QueueClient.Receive() with Broken Message

```
BrokeredMessage deadmessage = client.Receive();
byte[] dataRaw = deadmessage.GetBody<byte[]>();
```

Due to some corrupted data, I got the exception on second line, while get the body of the broken message. So i was try to get the body of the message on catch block with SteamReader.

```
Stream stream = deadmessage.GetBody<Stream>();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

I experienced with below exception, Could anyone help me with appropriate fixes?

Exception details :

The message body cannot be read multiple times. To reuse it store the value after reading.

Comment: The exception is pretty much self explanatory. You cannot access the body more than once and need to know what the payload is. If it's a byte[], then it's a byte array. If it's a stream, then access it as a stream. If message is corrupted, dead-letter it. Reading the body as one format and on exception attempt to read it as another format makes no sense.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I could like to clarify something to you, Basically, Original message will come as byte[] format. But some messages are invalid (As XML format). However i need to store the values to DB either valid / invalid. That is why, i read as byte[] on try and stream as catch. Please help me out, how to read BrokenMessage body more than once?

Comment: @GopinathM try moving the broken message to the Dead Letter Queue with [DeadLetter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.deadletter?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_DeadLetter_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary_System_String_System_Object__) and read it once from there.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually i am reading from dead Letter Queue only. This all functionality must read data from deadletter.

Comment: Why try with `byte[]` instead of `Stream` then? You already know these are bad messages.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos All the times i will not receive the bad messages. There is chance i will receive the good messages as well. That is why i am unable to get all the message over stream object.

Comment: First, you can check the `DeadLetterReason` and `DeadLetterErrorDescription` of the DLQ messages to see why they ended up there. Second, you don't know if a timed-out message is good or not. A Stream returns bytes too, so you don't need to use `byte[]` at all. Finally, you can set your own reason when you detect a badly formatted message in the happy scenario to differentiate malformed messages

Comment: You can create use a [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx) and copy the message's contents to it with `stream.CopyTo(myMemoryStream);` [MemoryStream.ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) will copy that data into a `byte[]` array

Comment: Another option is to Clone your message upon arrival. If your fail to process the message, then clone will be the other format. Frankly, I don't like the fact that message is of an unknown type and you have to resort to DLQ or other tricks. Sender should either comply to a standard or stamp a message with a header to indicate what format is used for the body. Who knows, tomorrow a 3rd option might emerge :D

Comment: You can use BrokeredMessage clone method. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869297/4140278)

Answer (score 2):

To take multiple attempts to read message body you need to read it as a stream first

```
serviceBusClient.GetBody<Stream>()
```

Then you can try to interpret it by different ways. For example it can be serialized directly by following way:

```
var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(message);
serviceBusClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
```

but it's better to serialize it to json first.

```
var brokeredMessage = new BrokeredMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
serviceBusClient.Send(brokeredMessage);
```

it's more safe in my view because json serialization ignores namespaces of message type, so you will not break your process when you move class of message to another namespace.

Suppose you are starting to send and read messages serialized in json but some old messages can be still binary serialized. In this case you can use the following logic:

```
    public static T DeserializeMessage<T>(BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage)
    {
        using (var stream = brokeredMessage.GetBody<Stream>())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            string bodyText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(bodyText);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException)
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(stream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max);
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                var msgBody = (T)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
                return msgBody;
            }
        }
    }
```

If you need to try to deserialize the message as another type, catch *System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException* on *serializer.ReadObject(reader)*.

Answer (score 1):

As Sean Feldman mentioned that if message is corrupted, then it will be handled by [dead-letter queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues).

> Service Bus queues and topic subscriptions provide a secondary sub-queue, called a dead-letter queue (DLQ). The dead-letter queue does not need to be explicitly created and cannot be deleted or otherwise managed independent of the main entity.
>   The purpose of the dead-letter queue is to hold messages that cannot be delivered to any receiver, or simply messages that could not be processed.

If you need to know how to create and user Service Bus Queue we can refer to [get start with Service Bus queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues)

> To reuse it store the value after reading.

If it be can be read correctly then we can store it messageid and vaule for  reuse.

The DLQ is mostly similar to any other queue.

If it is corrupted data, we can get it from the dead-letter queue as mormal queue.

```
  string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting('Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString');
  QueueClient Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, deletLetterQueueName);

  var message = Client.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
  if (message != null)
  {
     var ret = message.GetBody<stream>();
     message.Complete();
  }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? How is the OP going to read the *body* if `GetBody` throws? Are you implying that the body will appear in one of the message properties?

Answer (score 0):

I found another reason of the exception. The thing is that when I debugged different problem I got this exception. After some experiments I realized that Visual Studio reads the message behind the scene  to show it for example in Watch panel, and when my code tried to get the message it was already read by Visual Studio.
To avoid this it needs to wrap the message to a property with backing field, which will store the value. And then I realized that the exception message abstracly says to make this.

So you should consider that it can be read behind the scene