# Read BrokeredMessage body multiple time

Tags: azure, aop, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I know that error message is self-explanatory, we can't read message body multiple times. here I'm using AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) for audit log.

```
[AuditServiceMethod(AttributePriority = 0)]
[FunctionName("ValidateSubscriber")]
    public static async Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("validate-message", AccessRights.Manage,
        Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]BrokeredMessage message,
        TraceWriter log,
        [Inject(typeof(ICommonUtilities))] ICommonUtilities commonUtility)
    {
        string body;
        using (var stream = message.GetBody<Stream>())
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
}
```

**[AuditServiceMethod]** is my aspect for audit request, response and error log.
Is there any good workaround to get body multiple time in Azure function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [clone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.clone?view=azure-dotnet) `BrokeredMessage` and use the clone rather than the original message.

Comment: Perfect answer!